# Sequelize.select returns wrong dates

Tags: node.js, sql-server, reactjs, sequelize.js, utc

I am attempting to create a web (react/sequelize) front end to an existing database.

When I perform a select from the database the returns results in sequelize have the date as off by 1 (-1).

Here is the SQL and code used to get the data:

```
let sql1 = 'SELECT count(RECEIVED_DATE) as CallCount, CAST(RECEIVED_DATE AS DATE) as CallDate FROM TowCalls WHERE OFFICE_ID = ? AND (RECEIVED_DATE BETWEEN dateadd(day,?, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()) group by CAST(RECEIVED_DATE AS DATE) ORDER BY CAST(RECEIVED_DATE AS DATE)';
    models.sequelize.query(sql1,  { replacements: [id, -7], type: models.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
      .then(function(summary) {
```

When I output summary to the console I get:

```
[
  { CallCount: 22, CallDate: '2020-12-16' },
  { CallCount: 36, CallDate: '2020-12-17' },
  { CallCount: 20, CallDate: '2020-12-18' },
  { CallCount: 12, CallDate: '2020-12-19' },
  { CallCount: 28, CallDate: '2020-12-20' },
  { CallCount: 13, CallDate: '2020-12-21' },
  { CallCount: 1, CallDate: '2020-12-22' }
]
```

When I use the same query in SQL Server itself I get the same counts, but all the dates are +1.

Although I never specifically set it, I believe the dates are in SQL in EST timezone.

All the users of the database are in the same timezone so I never had to worry about tracking any changes.

Comment: Are you saying that your dates are off by one day? What is the data type of the `RECEIVED_DATE` column?

Comment: Yes, the last date in the list should be 2020-12-23, not the 22nd.
RECEIVED_DATE is a datetime column in MSSQL.
The value in that row in SQL Server is:  2020-12-23 01:30:00.000
I suspect it has something to do with UTC time and the conversion of the EST time to UTC.    But I am not sure how to deal with it.

Comment: Should I update all the dates in the database to be stored in UTC?
In my case I am assuming that would mean adding +5 hours to all the datetime columns.

Comment: I added 5 hours to the RECEIVED date and the returned dataset in sequelize still only contains 2020-12-22, where it should be 23rd.  The values of the count have changed, so I am not sure adding 5 hours is the way to go.

Comment: Could the issue have something to do with CAST I am performing on the date?
I changed to query to return the TOP(10) and RECEIVED_DATE (removing the COUNT, CAST and GROUP BY) and the values are correct.

Comment: Additional, testing the above test did return the correct dates, although they appear ar UTC dates (2020-12-23.000.000.000Z).  When I use them in a date object they are converted and changed to 2020-12-22.